# YouTube video list in JSON format

Tags: php, json, youtube

I have created a function in PHP for fetching a YouTube video list of my channel in JSON format but I'm getting blank array.

```
public function channels_list()
{

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method != 'GET')
    {
        json_output(400,array('status' => 400,'message' => 'Bad request.'));
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array();

        $json_link="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='MY API KEY'&channelId='MY CHANNEL ID'&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10";

        $json = file_get_contents($this->json_link);
        $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);                        

        foreach($obj['items'] as $post){

            $jsondata['id'] = isset($post['id']['videoId']) ? $post['id']['videoId'] : "";
            $jsondata['published_at'] = isset($post['snippet']['publishedAt']) ? $post['snippet']['publishedAt'] : "";
            $jsondata['title'] = isset($post['snippet']['title']) ? $post['snippet']['title'] : "";
            $jsondata['description'] = isset($post['snippet']['description']) ? $post['snippet']['description'] : "";
            $jsondata['thumbnail'] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$id}/maxresdefault.jpg";
            array_push($data, $jsondata);

        }
        json_output("200", array("list"=>$data),1);     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,I'm using this and it's working fine for me.

```
function get_youtube($url){

$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $url ."&format=json";

$curl = curl_init($youtube);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return json_decode($return, true);
}
$url = // youtube video url 

// Display Data 
print_r(get_youtube($url));
```

**Updated:**

you don't need OAuth2 login for that. You can simply do it by setting your API key instead.

It's a playlistItems->list request.

Here's demonstration in api explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=PLjFEz-E0UPUxw3lFpnfV1dDA7OE7YIFRj&_h=2&

Instead of setting clientId and client Secret

set it's API key to your API key from cloud console in Public API access.

```
$client->setAPIKey($API_KEY);
```

**Example:**

```
 $API_key    = 'Your_API_Key';
 $channelID  = 'YouTube_Channel_ID';
 $maxResults = 10;

 $videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));
```

Comment: Hi Beulah,I changed whole code still it is giving me blank array.. i opted your above mentioned way to fetch data

Comment: $videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));

Comment: foreach($videoList->items as $item){
   
    $jsondata['data'][$key]['id'] = $item->id->videoId;
    $jsondata['data'][$key]['published_at'] = $item->snippet->publishedAt;
    $jsondata['data'][$key]['title'] = $item->snippet->title;
    $jsondata['data'][$key]['description'] = $item->snippet->description;
    $jsondata['data'][$key]['thumbnail'] = $item->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
    array_push($data, $jsondata);
    
   }
   
  } 
  json_output(200, array("list"=>$data),1);